# QGis can't read ECW format after update

Tags: qgis

I have updated from 2.18.16 "Las Palmas" to 3.24 "Tisler". After that QGis can't read ECW format. This is the error:

```
Fuente de datos no admitida: path_to_file/mapaBTN25_epsg25830_0992-4.ecw no es un origen de datos ráster admitido
```

Something like:

```
 "Source of data is not accepted: file.ecw if not a valid format"
```

Doing in console:

```
gdalinfo --formats | grep ECW
```

I get:

```
 ECW -raster- (rw+): ERDAS Compressed Wavelets (SDK 5.4)
  JP2ECW -raster,vector- (rw+v): ERDAS JPEG2000 (SDK 5.4)
```

I remember a long time ago I had to install those libraries manually, but seems that they are fine (not sure).

My PC is recently updated to Linux Mint 20.1

output of `ogrinfo --version`:

```
GDAL 2.3.1, released 2018/06/22
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a question at all, there's a ticket to this effect but it's getting staled-out soon, replying there may get you help. https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/48174